# what change in function argument should I make to link to another page?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Hi all I am a newbie in web programming so please help me out in this problem. I am trying to make 2 drop down lists linked together which I got from another forum and then I am trying to link the go button to another webpage according to option selected. For going to another page i got the function but when I am trying to link it is not working

Here is the code.There are two functions 1. for linking drop down lists 2. for going to another page. but it is not working as i have written the onClick function go to a new page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options        above first',' ');

}
if (chosen == "1") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('http://www.google.com','oneone');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('first choice - option two','onetwo');
}
if (chosen == "2") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('second choice - option one','twoone');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('second choice - option two','twotwo');
}
if (chosen == "3") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('third choice - option one','threeone');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('third choice - option two','threetwo');
}
}
</script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function JumpToIt(frm) {
var newPage = frm.url.options[frm.url.selectedIndex].value
if (newPage != "None") {
    location.href=newPage
}
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<form name="myform"><div align="center">
<select name="optone" size="1"
onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options
[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">First Choice</option>
<option value="2">Second Choice</option>
<option value="3">Third Choice</option>
</select><br> <br>
<select name="opttwo" size="1">  
<option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above     first</option>
</select>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Go!" onClick="JumpToIt(this.myform)">
</div></form>
</html>
```

so someone please tell me what should i write in the onclick function so that it will go to the linked page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function setOptions(chosen) 
    { 
        var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;  
        selbox.options.length = 0; 

        if (chosen == " ") 
        { 
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options        above first',' ');  } 

            if (chosen == "1") { selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('http://www.google.com','oneone'); selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two','onetwo'); } 
            if (chosen == "2") { selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one','twoone'); selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two','twotwo'); } 
            if (chosen == "3") { selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one','threeone'); selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two','threetwo'); 
        } 
    } 

    function JumpToIt(frm) 
    { 
        var newPage = frm.opttwo.options[frm.opttwo.options.selectedIndex].value;


        if (newPage != "None") { location.href=newPage; } 
    } 

</script>

</head>
<form name="myform">
    <div align="center">
        <select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options [document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="1">First Choice</option>
            <option value="2">Second Choice</option>
            <option value="3">Third Choice</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="opttwo" size="1">
            <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
        </select>
        <input type="BUTTON" value="Go!" onclick="JumpToIt(document.myform)">
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: a few changes: 1) for JumpToIt, passing in the form object instead of 'this' which means the button.  2) use frm.opttwo instead of frm.url which is not defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood the problem. Also changing the "oneone" to the page address it takes to that page.

Answer (score 1):

Is the second dropdown populating correctly? I was under the impression that to create a new option you used the document.createElement("option") like so:

```
var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.text = "text";
opt.value = "value";
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = opt;
```

However, I believe the main problem is that there is no element with the id or name "url" within the form.  I believe you need to change

```
var newPage = frm.url.options[frm.url.selectedIndex].value
```

to

```
var newPage = frm.opttwo.options[frm.opttwo.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 1):

`<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Go!" onClick="JumpToIt(this.myform)">` here "this" refers to the input tag, which does not have a property of "myform".

You probably mean:

```
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Go!" onClick="JumpToIt('myform')">
```

But in this function:

```
function JumpToIt(frm) {
var newPage = frm.url.options[frm.url.selectedIndex].value
if (newPage != "None") {
    location.href=newPage
}
}
```

You're pass it a form name, but there is no element called "url" in your form, you have "opttwo", so swap in "opttwo" for "url" and this *might* work.